# Laravel: "No input file specified" when link to public folder

Tags: laravel

Update 2022-07-06:
I know what the problem is. It's because of "open_basedir". In Plesk support page, says that we can change this parameter, add new path. https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006170513

But our Plesk closed the edit privilege... I have to negotiate with the hosting company...

x x x x x x x x x x

My company have a website made by other company. Not laravel, not codeigniter, not any popular framework. Now I want to use laravel to make an new admin system.

The website uses Plesk system, DocumentRoot is /xxx/httpdocs. I tried a method which was ok:
move laravel/public to be newadmin
/httpdocs/newadmin

move other laravel folder inside laravelsrc
/httpdocs/newadmin/laravelsrc

Ok, it works fine.

But I think and many people said that this is not good to put files inside public folder. So  I want to use a different structure:

```
/httpdocs  
    newadmin  

/laravel  
    public
```

The newadmin is a symbolic link to laravel/public. It also works in my Windows 10, Apache. Great! Wonderful! I think it's so easy. Laravel is laravel, stays at where it should be. But Plesk doesn't work.

I ask my host machine's customer service to do the the command:

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/public /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/newadmin
```

Visit: http://mywebsite.com/newadmin, the page said:

```
No input file specified.
```

Nothing else. How to fix this?

Comment: hmm, the cause can be anything. i can think of its either rewrite or permission. can you tell us what OS you are running and the webserver you are using on [tag:Plesk]?

Comment: Linux Centos 7.9, Apache 2.x, php 7.4.  Maybe "composer dump-autoload" can solve this? But we don't have ssh permission.

Comment: You don't have SSH access? I really can't understand there are hosting companies that will not give access to SSH and still make you use an insecure FTP connection.  Maintaining a Laravel application without command line will be hard.

Comment: @ronrun if you think `dump-autoload` can solve the problem, you can upload your local copy of `vendor\autoload.php` after running it. though, whenever dealing with laravel app without ssh access, you can make a local working copy then upload it as workaround.

Comment: I know what the problem is. It's because of "open_basedir". In Plesk support page, says that we can change this parameter, add new path. But our Plesk closed the edit privilege... I have to negotiate with the hosting company. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of "open_basedir". In Plesk support page, says that we can change this parameter, add new path. https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006170513